# Progress Bar not animating while inserting data in Database using AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, animation, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I have edittext and button to insert data,when i click the button i am hiding the button and edittext and showing a ProgressBar.I am using AsyncTask to insert data in sqlite database, but the problem is, While performing background task,the ProgressBar is not animating.I am using progressbar with intermediateDrawable.

NOTE: ProgressBar is animating Perfectly in other classes,but when i insert data in database, its showing but not animating.

ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:visibility="gone"         
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/viewSpace3"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loader_0_1" />
```

loader_0_1.xml

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360" >

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:thicknessRatio="8"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dip"
        android:width="48dip" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="#0B95B9"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

In preExecute of AsyncTask i am hiding other widgets and showing progressBar pb, using

In doInBackground, i am inserting data in database using cursor

In PostExecute, i am hiding progressBar and showing other widgets

Here is my AsyncTask Method

```
private class SaveToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {         
                 sLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });          
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                     mdb=new DBHandler(CustomCVG.this, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                     db=mdb.getWritableDatabase();
                      db=mdb.getWritableDatabase();
                     for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

                         ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                         cv.put("VIN", vin_z);
                         cv.put("rotate", rotateStringList.get(i));

                         db.insert("imageUploadDb", null, cv);

                     }
                     db.close();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MGTActivity.class));
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 sLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is that a memory or RAM issue that doesn't allow progressBar to Animate while working with Databases...?

Comment: Post Async Task code too.

Comment: post running asyncTask code from activity or whereever you run it from. Did you try your progress bar animation at all? You could make it visible and run your activity with no actions so it should animate.

Comment: Since you are well aware of AsyncTask, I assume you used `onProgressUpdate` method for progress bar animation

Comment: I am not using any animation method at all for animation.I am just making it visible.Thats all @Stan

Comment: Actually you are using custom animation: `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loader_0_1"`. Ok, then make it visible in activity's `onCreate()` and see if it animates. Also maybe the whole DB job executes so fast that PB has no time to animate. 1-10 inserts executes really fast. However I suggest you to use transaction instead of your way of sql-inserts inside of cycle. Also you still didn't show how do you instantiate and run your AsyncTask.

Comment: worth a try. Will check right now.I am calling AsyncTask by using `new SaveToDatabase().execute("");`

Comment: @Stan that ain't working.Tried what u told.

Comment: Do u mean PB doesn't animate if you add it visible to an activity? If so then you should firstly first fix its animation. For example you could add an usual not customized round PB and see if it animates. Then check if it animates while yer AsyncTask is running. If it does with standard PB it must do it with your custom animation if custom ever work

Comment: Yeah....its showing but not animating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your background operation on the UI thread. What else you think

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  ....
}
```

does? OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute are already run on the UI thread, so you don't need it there. doInBackground runs on another thread, but you force it to run on the UI thread again... so no surprise the UI thread is busy and can't display your progress bar.

This is how it should look like :

```
private class SaveToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {      
    sLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 mdb=new DBHandler(CustomCVG.this, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                 db=mdb.getWritableDatabase();
                  db=mdb.getWritableDatabase();
                 for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

                     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                     cv.put("VIN", vin_z);
                     cv.put("rotate", rotateStringList.get(i));

                     db.insert("imageUploadDb", null, cv);

                 }
                 db.close();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MGTActivity.class));
}
```

}

Comment: Brother your answer made my life.I removed the database code from the `runOnUiThread` and also removed `runOnUiThread` from the onPostExecute method and it worked.Thanx for your effort,Means a lot.Answer Accepted.

Comment: Hey, glad it works, though your remark "I removed the database code" had me a bit puzzled. You should not remove the database code, just the runOnUiThread stuff. I edited my answer to show how it should look like. Good luck :)

Comment: Yeah buddy thats what i did.I removed runOnUiThread from from doInBackground and postExecute method.You were absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to ensure you custom ProgressBar animation (loader_0_1.xml) works at all. To do that you should add visible ProgressBar at your activity's layout:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:visibility="visible"         
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loader_0_1" />
```

It should animate if activity is idle (does nothing on UI htread). If it does not animates you should firstly first fix the animation.
Try to add a standard (not customized) round PB like:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/standard_round_pb"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

and see if it animates (spins) being added to an activity as mentioned before. Then check if it animates while yer AsyncTask is running. If it does with standard PB it must do it with your custom animation if custom animation ever work.
Also check if you run your AsyncTask properly like `new AsyncTask().execute()` and not like `new AsyncTask().doInBackground()`.
In general: If your UI thread (Activity) is busy doing something (no matter what, it should be completely idle) you wont see any PB animation at all, whatever you do.
Actually your problem is that you start AsyncTask's job on UI thread using `runOnUiThread()` - why do u do that? AsyncTask that way is useless.

Comment: i tried doing this.And its working perfectly fine.
And when AsyncTask is running,it animates if i call .NET web service inside AsyncTask.But when i work with sqlite inside AsyncTask,pb is not animating.\

Comment: Did you try standard round PB as well? Also try to load AsyncTask with any other job, even just `Thread.sleep(7000);` to make AsyncTaks's thread to sleep for a 7 seconds and see what happens.

Comment: Thanx for your efforts @Stan